# Exporting data from .mxd file to SQL Server database using C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, sql-server, mxd

I am using ArcGIS product (v.10.1). I have also tempalte of Maps from ArcGIS. But i need to get data from maps (.mxd files) to store it into MS SQL database.
Explanation: I have application that has map in it's window. When i click on some city on map i get name of the city and it's coordinates and save them into DB. Problem - i need to have list of cities in database before i click on map to make some custom autocomplete for textBox.

---

I read some articles about getting data using Python, but i don't know this language. 
Any advices how to export data from mxd files?

---

Note:
I am using C# to work with data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use C# with the ArcGIS Platform I recommend that you review the [ArcObjects API Reference for .NET](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004800000124000000), and in particular this [ArcMap Overview](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/000t00000006000000/).

Something to be aware of at the outset is that little (some annotation is one exception) or no spatial data is stored in *.mxd files.  Consequently, I suspect that what you are looking to do is to access spatial data via layers in *.mxd files in order to locate their external sources and any applicable filters and use them to copy the data from its sources to an SQL Server repository.

Comment: well, you are wright. I have simple database. But i need to use data from layers. And it will be very good to save data from layer before i start to manage it. (on click on layer, i save name and coordinates of clicked city, but i need to know before what cities can be clicked ) This is hard for me to explain.

Comment: @user2167382 I recommend that you either use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these additional details, or if you think you are now asking a new question then use the Ask Question button to do so.  Although it may be hard to explain your issue(s), I encourage you to try to do so because a key feature of Stack Exchange sites is that they serve to help developers, analysts, etc improve their technical writing skills.